# Is there an available messageFormater or messageBuilder for contentType binary/x-gzip in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Currently having an error **Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x8b (at char #2, byte #-1)**.

The response is currently zipped and would like to know how to transform the received message into xml format. The response for the service at soapUI has a **Content-Type: binary/x-gzip**.

What can be the messageFormater and messageBuilder in WSO2 in order to parse the data received? Or, what type of property should be used?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `BinaryRelayBuilder` and `ExpandingMessageFormatter` to just pass data through the ESB without built or formatted. This [message builder and message formatter](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Configuring+Message+Relay) need to added into the axis2.xml file located in <EI_HOME>/conf/axis2 directory.